# SQLite on iPhone, can't get one row result

Tags: ios, sqlite

I didn't find out how to get single row query result in SQLite using iOS native library.
In fact I need it to make a COUNT(*) but the only way I found out is:

```
- (int)HowManyInMyDB:(int)user_id {

int isInDB = 0;


NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM USER WHERE user_id=%d;", user_id];

const char * sql = [query UTF8String];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;



if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &statement, nil)

    == SQLITE_OK) {

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        isInDB++;

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

}

    return isInDB;

}
```

but I don't think it is a reliable way, am I right ?
When I do a COUNT(*) query i didn't find out how to catch simply the answer.
Thanks in advance for answers !
ByeBye

Comment: Side note - do not use string formats to generate the query string. Make proper use of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind a value to the query.

Comment: Save yourself much trouble and use fmdb (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to access the DB. Use `FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable"];` rather than the low-level sqlite3_ APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach (note the use of `sqlite3_bind_int` to apply the `user_id`):

```
- (int)HowManyInMyDB:(int)user_id {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE user_id=?", -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, user_id);

        int count = 0;
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        }

        // Finalize the statement
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        return count;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database) );
    }

    return -1; // indicate an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to find the number of rows in your USER table with the same user_id? You should use a SQL query like "SELECT COUNT(*) AS answer FROM USER WHERE user_id = %d". This will produce one row of output, and that output will have an entry 'answer' where the value is the number you want. You'll need to use the SQLite API to read 1 row, and take the value from its 'answer' entry. So you'll call sqlite3_step() one time, sqlite3_column_count() one time to double-check that you received a result (it should return 1) and sqlite3_column(statement, 0) one time, to get the result from the first column.